# Azure DevOps (VSTS): How to stop a subsequent release pipeline overwriting staging before swapping staging to production on the current release?

Tags: azure-devops, rollback, release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have the following release pipeline set up in Azure Dev Ops for web deployments:

[Release Pipeline - Web Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihQX9.jpg)

How this is configured...

- Continuous Deployment is enabled
- The **Development** stage is triggered after release, has no pre-deployment approval and will deploy the artifact to the dev slot.
- The **Test and staging** stages are triggered after the previous stage, have pre-deployment and post deployment approvals enabled and will deploy the artifact to the relevant slot.
- The **Production** stage are triggered after the previous stage, has only pre-deployment enabled and will *swap* the staging slot with the production slot.
- The **rollback** stage is manually triggered, has only pre-deployment approvals enabled and will *swap* the staging slot with the production slot.

I understand that when an approval for a stage is still pending, another release can't be deployed to that stage.  For example R1 is waiting post deployment approval on the test stage, therefore no subsequent releases (R2, R3, etc.) can queue the pre-deployment on the test stage.  I'm also aware on the Deployment queue settings functionality but don't think this helps here - happy to be wrong.

So my question is...

**Is there an *automated* way to stop a subsequent release overwriting the staging slot before we have approved the production stage, which swaps staging to production, for the current release?**

and my example is...

Post deployment on the staging slot for Release 1 (R1) has been approved.  This means 1) that the pre-deployment on the production stage (swap staging to production) can be approved for R1 and 2) the staging slot on R1 is "free" to be deployed to from another Release.  So now, R2 could have pre-deployment for the staging stage approved, meaning it will deploy R2 to staging potentially before we swap staging to production for R1.  As such, if we approve R1 to production, we will swap R2 into production, not R1 as intended.  *Still with me!*  Also, we don't want R2 being deployed to staging until we have possibly approved the production stage, so that if we need to rollback (swap production to staging) we are swapping in the original version, not R2.

I hope that makes sense.  Obviously this could be managed manually to avoid this scenario but hopefully someone might be able to advise how this might be achievable automatically.

FYI - first Stack Overflow post, so go easy on me if I've not follow protocol ;) and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you deploying same artifacts to all environments, no change in config etc.. ?